# Android market accounts: are they, all, *@gmail.com?

Tags: android, gmail, account

The accounts of Android Market, that are linked with the Google Checkout system, have all the syntax as xyz@gmail.com? Are all of them with the last characters with "@gmail.com"? Or also as "@googlemail.com" or other?

Comment: Why? And is this programming related?

Comment: Obvious. I need to sign in users in my app with the android market account (to check if they paid for my app). And I was thinking to test if the account ended with "@gmail.com". Now, after the community answers, I think that I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they need not be @gmail.com accounts. They must be either Gmail or Google Apps accounts. Google Apps accounts can have any domain name.

Comment: So, there is the next question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055755/getting-android-market-account-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

I have a ...@googlemail.com account.

Comment: Ouch, I click  +1 but "Vote up requires 15 reputation". So... thank you! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

as the Gmail and Android both are the babies of Google. It might possible... nothing strange if it accepts gmail domain email accounts

Answer (score 0):

Apparently so, I'd have thought it was possible to link a non-Gmail account but it doesn't seem like it is..