# Getting Android Market Account programmatically

Tags: android, gmail, google-play, account

To get the Android Market Account, I do so:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
androidCheckout = accounts[0].name.trim().toLowerCase();
```

With my phone and my credentials the above statement is fine.
I've an account so masked: "something@gmail.com".

My question is: I know that the accounts can be either Gmail or Google Apps accounts. And also that Google Apps accounts can have any domain name. So, in this case, instead of @gmail.com there can be everything: depending on the domain name, for instance "cippalippa.us", the account could be "geltrude@cippalippa.us". In this case, the above statement will still be ok??

Answer (score 0):

> `Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");`

it will work only for google accounts. You can use `getAccounts()` instead `getAccountsByType()`, now `accounts` will be a list of all the sync accounts. You can easily extract your desired account using `accounts.name` and `accounts.type`